# No JTA platform available Spring boot 3.2.0

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, maven, jackson-databind

Earlier I had jackson core and jackson datatype dependencies in pom.xml. I removed these dependencies as they are already added by **spring-boot-starter-parent 3.2.0**. I get all needed **spring 6.1.1** dependencies and **jackson 2.15.3** dependencies from the parent automatically. But I get error while running the application **No JTA platform available (set hibernate transaction jta platform to enable JTA platform integration)** Could you please tell if this error is because of incorrect dependencies?

Comment: JTA platform has little to do with Jackson. Also, spring-boot-starter-parent inherits from spring-boot-dependencies, which does little else than providing dependency management. It does not add dependencies to the project. (check differences of dependencies vs dependencyManagement in Maven). So "I removed these dependencies as they are already added by spring-boot-starter-parent 3.2.0." is not correct.

Comment: That is not an error that is in information message.